# How can i put Deny Assignment in Azure Subscription or Resource Group level?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to put a Deny Rule on the subscription so that the contributor access can be overridden with the custom role with some exceptions.

I found the article on MS portal ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments ), though not able to get any example how this can be implemented.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to apply Contributor access and then just have your deny rules in the Custom Role? What scenarios have you tested so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Azure Blueprints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview), you can't directly create your own deny assignments, deny assignments are created and managed by Azure, e.g.  Azure Blueprints.

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments#how-deny-assignments-are-created) explains that:

> Deny assignments are created and managed by Azure to protect resources. For example, Azure Blueprints and Azure managed apps use deny assignments to protect system-managed resources. For more information, see [Protect new resources with Azure Blueprints resource locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/tutorials/protect-new-resources).

Comment: Thanks Joy, i had the same feeling. Was trying out the blueprint, which applies lock rather than any deny permissions

Comment: Thanks Joy, it seems like the suggested approach is the only way for now. Microsoft is working on custom definition which will help fulfilling the requirement.