# Azure ARM policy to deny role assignments only by resource group owners

Tags: azure, policy, rbac

I have a requirement where I need to deny only owners of the resource group to do new role assignments or changes to existing role assignments.

Resource group contributors and readers anyways cannot do any role assignments/modifications.

Role assignments/modifications should be done by Subscription level and Management level Owners only and of course by Admins.

I did followed this github article but there is no way to restrict only owners of resource group.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/Authorization/allowed-role-definitions/azurepolicy.json

I create below policy but this denies everyone to role assignments/modifications:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Effect of this Azure Policy - Audit, Deny or Disabled"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Deny",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Deny"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay,

This is not yet solved, can you help please-
Is there any way in Azure Policies to get the "user scope", like what scope the user has- RG owner or subscription owner.
my requirement is:
1. Check user is resource group owner-
2. if Yes - deny "role assignments"
3. If No - Allow "role assignments" for for Admins and Subscription owners - that is default

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,we can not create deny assignments directly, As shown in portal that "***Deny assignments block users from performing specific actions even if a role assignment grants them access. At this time, the only way you can add your own deny assignments is by using [Azure Blueprints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview)***."

[image]

To achieve this by using blueprint please refer this [***MICROSOFT TOTORIAL| Protect new resources with Azure Blueprints resource locks***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/tutorials/protect-new-resources)

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***MICRSOFT DOCUMENT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments#how-deny-assignments-are-created)
- [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717919/how-can-i-put-deny-assignment-in-azure-subscription-or-resource-group-level)

Comment: Sorry, this is not helping me preventing only Resource Group owners to prevent role assignments. Either it prevents everyone to do role assignments - like subscription owners, admins as well OR will allow everyone to do assignments.

Comment: Is there no way in Policies to get the "user scope", like where the user is - RG owner or subscription owner.
my requirement is:
1. Check user is resource group owner-
2. if Yes - deny "role assignments"
3. If No - Allow "role assignments" for for Admins and Subscription owners - that is default