# Unable to remove/deactivate azure container apps revisions due to ResourceGroup level deny assignment

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I am not able to deactivate azure container app revisions and they are consuming my subscription.
I have a container app which has many revisions, the status of revisions are running, previsioning status are Provisioned, when I try to deactivate revisions and save it shows weired message provided in picture.[image: error message]

In attached picture you can see permissions that I have [image]

Revision Mode is multiple but when I change it to single it hangs and does shows this uninformative message [image: message]

and the image of my deny assignment [image]
please help me to resolve this problem, the idle usage of memory and vCPU consumes my subscription per day.

when I click on deny assignment it shows that it is currently read only
[image]

Comment: Try, when you delete the deny assignment on Resource group Level.

Comment: when I go to the appropriate resource group Access Control (IAM) I see the deny assignment in the Deny assignments tab, but I do not see there a way to delete it or detach it from the resource group, and when I click on deny assignment there it opens in a new window showing that deny assignment is read-only, attached a picture of that you can see it

Comment: Deny assignments are assigned from blueprints. If you have owner access at the subscription level, kindly navigate to `Blueprints > Assigned blueprints > check the blueprints` that are assigned to your resource group and [unassign](https://i.imgur.com/ir8fBFR.png) them.

Comment: I do not have any Azure blueprint and have not created any, the deny assignment was created automatically

Comment: Select the name in the deny assignment section and check its origin to determine if it was created from blueprints or not, As per Microsoft deny assignment is only possible through blueprints.

Comment: Refer the stack link about [deny assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717919/how-can-i-put-deny-assignment-in-azure-subscription-or-resource-group-level).